# Динамическое наследование в php

Tags: php

Всем привет!
У меня есть репозиторий который используется для нескольких проектов (типа CMS). Выводимый контент на тех или иных страницах немного отличается, где-то нужно использовать какие-то функции, где-то нет. Возникает проблема в большом кол-ве заспамленности кода и большом колличестве условий if()...if()..if(). Хотелось бы как-то разделить проекты и наследовать только нужные мне классы. Но к сожалению реализовать так называемое динамическое наследование никаким образом не получается (или всё же есть какие-то варианты?). Какие способы решения есть в данной проблеме (кроме разделения проектов)?

Comment: Уберите метку php поставьте метку git или svn, судя по тексту ваш вопрос не имеет отношения к php :)

Comment: Если проблема только в разном выводе, то используйте шаблонизаторы, и разделите шаблоны для каждого проекта в разные папки.

Comment: Тогда будет дублирование кода, а хотелось бы использовать базовый функционал + разделение на проекты

Comment: а кто вам мешает сделать дефолтную папку с шаблонами, а по проектам перекрывать только  используемые?

Comment: хм, может какую-то систему пермишынов создать, конечно от ифов не избавитесь, но сможете присваивать проектам нужные куски кода